# Python XLSXWRITE Is there a limit on the number of columns that can be created?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I have created a Python script that reads from a SQL server table containing 56 columns using a `sql_command` block

```
...
    db_cursor.execute(sql_command)
    rows = db_cursor.fetchall()
    worksheet.set_column('A:A',11)       #[BRAND] [varchar](10) NULL,
...
    worksheet.set_column('BD:BD',11)       #[NEWBUSINESS_RENEWAL] [varchar](1) NULL
...
    worksheet.write('A1','BRAND', Headerfm)
...
    worksheet.write('BD1','NEWBUSINESS_RENEWAL', Headerfm)
```

At this point I use a for loop on rows and write the row and column

```
    for Brand, ...NEWBUSINESS_RENEWAL in (rows)  
        worksheet.write(xlrow, xlcol, BRAND, Cellfm2)
        worksheet.write(xlrow, xlcol + 1, SUBCOMPANY, Cellfm1) 
...
        worksheet.write(xlrow, xlcol + 55, NEWBUSINESS_RENEWAL, Cellfm1)
        xlrow += 1
    workbook.close()
```

This then throws the error or message
        Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Cognos_Testing\Esri\python\xlsexport_v2.py", line 282, in 
    for BRAND,SUBCOMPANY,GROUP_,COVERAGE,POLICY_NUMBER,POLICY_INFORCE_DATE,POLICY_START_DATE,POLICY_END_DATE,POLCOUNT,RISKCOUNT,SUM_INSURED,REGISTRATION,MAKE,MODEL,YEAR_MANUFACTURED,TOWN,POSTCODE,STATE_,STREET_NUMBER,STREET_NAME,STREET_SUFFIX,STREET_OTHERDETAILS,GEOCODED_TOWN,GEOCODED_POSTCODE,GEOCODED_STATE,GEOCODED_STREET_NAME,INSURED_NAME,INSURED_HOMEPHONE,INSURED_WORKPHONE,INSURED_MOBEPHONE,INSURED_OTHERPHONE,INSURED_EMAIL,SECOND_INSURED_NAME,SECOND_INSURED_HOMEPHONE,SECOND_INSURED_WORKPHONE,SECOND_INSURED_MOBEPHONE,SECOND_INSURED_EMAIL,AGENCY_NAME,BROKER,FLOOD_FLAG,FLOOD_PREMIUM,FLOOD_COVERAGE,FLOOD_RISK_CONTENTS,FLOOD_RISK_BUILDING,BUSHFIRE_RATING,EMBARGO,YEAR_CONSTRUCTED,CONSTRUCTION_TYPE,ROOF_TYPE,WALLTYPE,FLOORTYPE,UNIT_FLAG,HH_HIGH_RISK_AREA_FLAG,POLICY_STATUS,POLICY_PAID,NEWBUSINESS_RENEWAL in (rows):
ValueError: too many values to unpack

Comment: Looks like you have less columns than others in one of your rows. Please post full traceback of your error message.

Comment: The problem is with your `for` line as I guessed. You have less than 35 columns in your `rows`. Try looping using `for row in rows:` and printing the `row` inside the loop to check if this is the case.

Comment: sorry I used the wrong trace back.  I've edited and added the first trace into the post.

Comment: Ok as you say there must be a mismatch here

Comment: ok you were spot on... it turned out to be a mismatch.  I had one extra column.. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the author's problem was solved without answering the question, but nontheless documentation [says](http://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_cell_notation.html) that "XlsxWriter supports Excels worksheet limits of **1,048,576 rows by 16,384 columns**."